# weighted median, but manually typed weights, not frequencies

Tags: matrices, python, median, vectorization

Since theres some contoversy about the definition of the weighted median, I wonder if my doing is even possible:

I have a large 2d matrix

```
[[ 1.1,  7.8,  3.3, 4.9], #<- row 1
[ 6.1,  9.8,  5.3, 7.9],  #<- row 2
[ 4.1,  4.8,  3.3, 7.1],  #<- row 3
... 
[ 1.1,  7.4,  3.1, 4.9], 
[ 7.1,  3.8,  7.3, 8.1],  
[ 19.1,  2.8,  3.2, 1.1]] #<- row n
```

and a set of weights for every position in each row. (each row is 4 elements long, so there will be 4 weights)

```
[0.64, 0.79, 0.91, 0]
```

Now: how does one calculate a weighted median for every single row, when the rowelements are weighted by the weights list (warning: NOT multiplied).
Like this: the first element always has an impact of 0.64, the second of 0.79, ... and the last one has no impact (zero). By impact we mean a measure of occourence.

How to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following for each row:

0. Normalize the weights.
1. Sort the row, keeping track of the corresponding weight.
2. Go through the list and keep a running tally of the weights. When you hit 0.5, obtain the median using the two corresponding entries.

Here is some python code to illustrate what I mean. The below script prints the median of the first row of the matrix.

Corrected code:

```
import numpy as np

wgt = [0.64, 0.79, 0.91, 0] #get normalized weights
wgt = np.array(wgt)
wgt /= sum(wgt) 

mat = [[ 1.1,  7.8,  3.3, 4.9],\
[ 6.1,  9.8,  5.3, 7.9],\
[ 4.1,  4.8,  3.3, 7.1],\
[ 1.1,  7.4,  3.1, 4.9],\
[ 7.1,  3.8,  7.3, 8.1],\
[ 19.1,  2.8,  3.2, 1.1]]
mat = np.array(mat)
n,m = np.shape(mat)

row_tups = sorted(list(zip(mat[:,0],wgt))) #<-sort the elements in increasing order,
i = 0                                        #keeping track of which elt is paired 
wgt_sum = 0                                  #with which wgt
while wgt_sum < 0.5:                      #<-stop when we hit cumulative wgt of 0.5,          
    wgt_sum += row_tups[i][1]                #corresponding to 50th percentile
    i += 1
med = row_tups[i-1][0]
print(med)
```

---

In detail, here's what the code does for the example presented.

First, get the normalized weight array `wgt`, which is `[0.274, 0.338, 0.389, 0]`. You can verify that these weights sum to $1$.

Next, we take the (first) row `mat[:,0]` and produce `list(zip(mat[:,0],wgt))`, which is a list of tuples consisting of the row-entry paired with its weight. That is, `list(zip(mat[:,0],wgt))` is the array

```
[(1.1, 0.274),
 (6.1, 0.338),
 (4.1, 0.389),
 (1.1, 0.0)]
```

We sort this so that the row-entries are increasing to get `row_tups`, which is

```
[(1.1, 0.0),
 (1.1, 0.274),
 (4.1, 0.389),
 (6.1, 0.338)]
```

I interpret the weights in the following way: 0% of the population has value 1.1, another 27.4% of the population has value 1.1, another 38.9% of the population has value 4.1, and another 33.8% of the population has value 6.1.

To compute the median value, I therefore go through the values in increasing order until I hit a total of 50%. In particular, we go through the loop to end up with $$
\text{prev_val} = 1.1, \quad \text{prev_wgt} = 0.274, \quad
\text{next_val} = 4.1, \quad \text{next_wgt} = 0.389.
$$
`next_wgt` is the first weight for which the running total of weights (in this case, $0 + 0.274 + 0.389$) exceeds $0.5 = 50\%$. At this point, I took the median to be the weighted average of the values $0.274$ and $0.389$.

However, I think that the more appropriate behavior is to simply state that the median is $0.389$.

---

Original code:

```
import numpy as np

wgt = [0.64, 0.79, 0.91, 0] #get normalized weights
wgt = np.array(wgt)
wgt /= sum(wgt) 

mat = [[ 1.1,  7.8,  3.3, 4.9],\
[ 6.1,  9.8,  5.3, 7.9],\
[ 4.1,  4.8,  3.3, 7.1],\
[ 1.1,  7.4,  3.1, 4.9],\
[ 7.1,  3.8,  7.3, 8.1],\
[ 19.1,  2.8,  3.2, 1.1]]
mat = np.array(mat)
n,m = np.shape(mat)

row_tups = sorted(list(zip(mat[:,0],wgt))) #<-sort the elements in increasing order,
i = 0                                        #keeping track of which elt is paired 
prev_wgt = 0                                 #with which wgt
next_wgt = 0
wgt_sum = 0
next_val = 0
while wgt_sum <= 0.5:                      #<-stop when we hit cumulative wgt of 0.5, 
    prev_val,prev_wgt = next_val,next_wgt    #corresponding to 50th percentile
    next_val,next_wgt = row_tups[i]
    wgt_sum += next_wgt
    i += 1
med = (prev_wgt*prev_val + next_wgt*next_val)/(prev_wgt + next_wgt)
print(med)
```

Comment: this looks interesting: could you comment the ```while wgt_sum <= 0.5:
    prev_val,prev_wgt = next_val,next_wgt
    next_val,next_wgt = row_tups[i]
    wgt_sum += next_wgt
    i += 1
med = (prev_wgt*prev_val + next_wgt*next_val)/(prev_wgt + next_wgt)``` aspect out a little bit?

another question: this is not just multiplying by the wieghts, but weighting the influence onto the median right?

Comment: To your second question: that is correct, I am not just multiplying by the weights. To your first: I added a bit of commentary, but it might be more instructive to run through an example

Comment: @HR_quantile See my latest edit

Comment: @HR_quantile In order to make my updated version rigorously correct, we should handle the case where wgt_sum hits 50 exactly separately, and return an average of two adjacent values in this case. Note in particular that the current version does return the true median with, for instance, a weight set $[1,1,1,1,1,1]$ and row $[1,2,3,4,5,6]$.